# How to configure Spring Security URL authorisation?

Tags: spring-security, jwt

I have configured my `SecurityFilterChain` thus:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    ....
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/user/*").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/user").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/auth/login").anonymous()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Yet, the URL paths are open to any authenticated user irregardless of the assigned role.
I have debugged the request filter to confirm that the `Principal` has the right role yet a `USER` role can call the protected URLs successfully.

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.5.

Comment: please dont write a custom JWTFilter, writing custom security is bad practice and instead use the built in jwt functionality that comes with spring boot https://thomasandolf.medium.com/spring-security-jwts-getting-started-ebdb4e4f1dd1

Comment: What is your question. Your code is working as you wrote. What do you want?

Answer (score 1):

If the path you're calling matches the authorization rule that you've declared as the last one (i.e. `anyRequest().authenticated()`), that implies that your test-requests **don't** match any of your rules that are meant to guard URLs that should be accessible only for Admins, namely:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/user/*").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/user").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
```

***Reminder:** the matching rule declared first always weens*

So, either HTTP-method or URL don't match (or both). For instance, if you're sending `GET` request, these restrictions would not be applied.

Regarding the URL, it should match **exactly** because you're using `antMatchers()`. I.e. path `"/api/user"` would not match other existing aliases of that path like `"/api/user/"` (*more on that see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28552)*).

That's one of the reasons why in Spring Security 6.0 `antMatchers()` (as well as `mvcMathcers()` and `regexMatchers()`) have been removed from the API and replaced [`requestMatchers()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.html#requestMatchers(java.lang.String...)).

So make sure that HTTP-method is correct and path you're calling matchers exactly, and consider updating the Spring dependencies and switching to using new request-securing methods.

If you have no planes to update soon, then you can make use of the `mvcMatchers()`, which use Spring MVC matching rules (i.e. they take into consideration all the existing aliases of the given path), instead of `antMatchers()`.

Here's an example of how your configuration might be implemented with Spring Security 6.0 and Lambda DSL (if you feel more comfortable with chaining configuration options using `and()` this flavor of DSL is still supported as well):

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .cors(cors -> cors.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/user/*").hasRole("ADMIN") // in Spring Security 6.0 method access() has been changed, and you don't need it anyway to verify the Role
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/user").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("/auth/login").anonymous()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement(sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this by the way. I still couldn't get it to work for the moment, but I can't upgrade to springboot 3.0 for the time being due to some deps not being version compatible as of yet,

Comment: @DarkStar1 If you have no planes to upgrade shortly, I would recommend to replacing `antMatchers()` with `mvcMatchers()`. And to illustrate the issue, can you add a screenshot from the client (Postman/Curl, whatever you're using)?